# JSON format in wordpress database

Tags: json, wordpress

I need to import JSON data in a WP database. I  found the correct  table of the database but the example JSON data present in table is not in a normal JSON format.

I need to import:
`{"nome": "Pippo","cognome": "Paperino"}`

but the example data in the table is:
`a:2:{s:4:"nome";s:5:"Pippo";s:7:"cognome";s:8:"Paperino";}`

How i can convert my JSON to "WP JSON"?

Comment: Making question clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is serialized, that's why it looks weird. You can use `maybe_unserialize()` in WordPress, this function will unserialize the data if it was serialized.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/maybe_unserialize/

Some functions serialize data before saving it in wordpress, and some will also unserialize when pulling from the DB. So depending on how you save it, and how you later extract the data, you might end up with serialized data.